# How to pass or get the QR Scan details showed in a text view to a string?

Tags: android, string, textview

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    final Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
                    result.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override`enter code here`
                        public void run() {
                            result.setText(barcode.displayValue);
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }
}
```

// The above is an object (result) getting barcode values to textview //

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl + hover on `displayValue` should show you its type. In case of int/float/double/long, you can use

```
String value = String.valueOf(barcode.displayValue);
```

In case it's a String, you can use

```
String value = barcode.displayValue
```

and in any other case, you can use

```
String value = barcode.displayValue.toString();
```

Or, to answer your question directly - to get String from TextView, you can use

```
String value = textview.getText().toString();
```

where `textView` is your instance of `TextView` (in this case, I suppose it's `result`

Comment: @KCSWebTechnologiesCLIENTS you should accept the answer (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the me credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.